# Nexus card expired and waiting for new one in the mail

Tags: nexus

I completed my interview June 10, 2019 for my Nexus and was approved.  They said it will take between 3 - 4 weeks to receive my new card in the mail.

I forgot to ask if I can continue to use my old card while I wait for new card.
I was able to do this the last time I renewed as I was crossing the border the same day.

Everything is the same except I am now using my maiden name.

Comment: Is your card actually expired, or did you just change your name?

Comment: My card expired March 13.  I submitted my renewal in January and had my interview June 10

Answer (score 3):

You can continue to use your expired card for up to six months whether or not you've completed the interview so long as you've reached the conditional approval stage.

See [this page](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1332/~/i-have-submitted-my-trusted-traveler-application-for-review.-did-cbp-receive-my):

> If you submitted a renewal application before expiration of your current membership, then you can continue to use your benefits until the renewal is finalized (up to 6 months after your expiration date).